# How to get file's relative path in git aliases with parameters?

Tags: git, parameters, relative-path, git-alias

I have the following aliases in my `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
  lg = log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --date=relative --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)' --all
  log-between = "!f() { git lgl `git merge-base $2 $1`..$2 -- $3 ; }; f"
  log-between-p = "!g() { git lgl -p $(git merge-base $2 $1)..$2 -- $3 ; }; g"
  diff-between = "!h() { echo $(pwd); git diff $(git merge-base $2 $1) $2 -- $3 ; }; h"
```

While it works fine in most of the cases the problem arises when I would like to get a log of a file (or a path) passing in the third parameter (`$3`) to diff-between.

The issue is that the command (`h` in this example) is being executed in the root directory of this repository (that's why I added `pwd` printing for checking) and I am passing in the name of the file or a path with a name but not always the absolute path.

E.g.

When I run this alias (added command printing to check to what command it will expand):

```
  diff-between = "!h() { echo $(pwd); echo "git diff $(git merge-base $2 $1) $2 -- $3" ; }; h"
```

under `repo_root_dir/src/` like so:

```
git diff-between origin/master my_branch
```

I will get:

```
git diff 66efa91ba8c74aa624d05d9ec0b13cc93cbfb6d3 my_branch --
```

which is fine. But when I run this like so (with a file):

```
git diff-between origin/master my_branch some_other_subdir/src/Base.cpp
```

I will get:

```
git diff 66efa91ba8c74aa624d05d9ec0b13cc93cbfb6d3 my_branch -- some_other_subdir/src/Base.cpp
```

regardless of where this command has been run from (**NOTE**: bear in mind that this is run from the root_dir of this repo)

---

How to properly get the **current directory** so that:

- having file `root_dir/src/some_other_subdir/Base.cpp`
- when I'm in `root_dir/src` and run my alias with `some_other_subdir/Base.cpp` parameter I get the following result
- **NOTE**: `pwd` inside git alias will return `root_dir`

Comment: not so sure about this. but, can you maybe try to change the `diff-between` alias into something like this? `"!h() { echo $(pwd); git diff $(git merge-base $2 $1) $2 -- $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)\/$3 ; }; h"`

Comment: @kucing_terbang `$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)` this will show the absolute path to root dir of repo which is easy to get e.g. by `$(pwd)` since this will be the directory from which the commands will be executed.

Comment: aaa. ok, I think I'm confused on what you want here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Git aliases are normally executed within the current directory. Except git aliases that execute in a shell (start with `!`). If a shell is started the shell's working dir will be the repository root.

Use the `${GIT_PREFIX:-./}` variable. It will resolve to the absolute repository path of the current directory.

```
diff-between = "!h() { git diff $(git merge-base $2 $1) $2 -- ${GIT_PREFIX:-./}$3 ; }; h"
```

Comment: You sir are a true genius :) Where did you get the info about that 'variable'?

Comment: From the release notes... ;) See https://github.com/git/git/blob/77bd3ea9f54f1584147b594abc04c26ca516d987/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.6.txt#L29-L31

Comment: But you can also use the git command `git rev-parse --show-prefix`

Comment: Thanks! I had to add `cd ${GIT_PREFIX:-./};` to the beginning of my alias because it didn't take relative paths.